# MySQL Query Problems with PHP in search form

Tags: php, mysql, get

I have written a basic PHP Site which passes a parameter from one page to another and queries a mysql database.

I have checked that the parameter has passed OK, but the where parameter on the query does not seem to be working.  Could anyone help?

The site is www.retroseek.co.uk and the search box is on the bottom. Many thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<title>Retro Computing Resource - RetroSeek Search</title>

<meta charset="UTF-8">


<style>
table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid green;
}

th {
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
}
</style>


</head>

<body>

<h1>Results from the RetroSeek Search Engine</h1>

<?php 

echo "<h1>Testing the GET has worked " . $_GET["query"] . "</h1>";


require( '../connect_db.php' ) ;

$query = $_GET['query']; 


$query = htmlspecialchars($query); 


$query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);

echo "<h1>Testing the GET has worked " . $_GET["query"] . "</h1>";



    $min_length = 4;
    // you can set minimum length of the query if you want


$q = "SELECT fgames.fgname, fgames.fgprorg, fgames.fgprbud, fgames.fgratng, fgames.fgprdsk, ftypes.fttname, frefs.fryymm, frefs.frpage, frefs.frissue, fmagzne.fmname, frefcde.ffname
FROM fgames, ftypes,frefs, fmagzne,frefcde
WHERE ftypes.fttype = fgames.fgtype
and   fgames.fglink = frefs.frlink2
and   frefs.frentry = frefcde.ffentry
and   frefs.frmag = fmagzne.fmmag 
and   fgames.fgname LIKE '%".$query."%'" ;



$r = mysqli_query( $dbc , $q ) ;

if( $r ) 
{


  echo '<table><tr><th>FGNAME</th><th>FGPRORG</th><th>FGRBUD</th><th>FGRATNG</th><th>FGRDSK</th><th>FTTTNAME</th><th>FRYYMM</th><th>FRPAGE</th><th>FRISSUE</th><th>FMNAME</th><th>FFNAME</th></tr>';

  while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $r , MYSQLI_ASSOC ) ) 
  {
    echo '<tr><td>'.$row['fgname'].'</td><td>'.$row['fgprorg'].'</td><td> '.$row['fgprbud'].' </td><td>'.$row['fgratng'].' </td><td>'.$row['fgprdsk'].' </td><td>'.$row['fttname'].'</td><td> '.$row['fryymm'].'</td><td> '.$row['frpage'].'</td><td> '.$row['frissue'].' </td><td>'.$row['fmname'].' </td><td>'.$row['ffname'].'</td></tr>';
  }
  echo '</table>';
}

else
{
  echo '<p>' . mysqli_error( $dbc ) . '</p>'  ;
}

show_records($dbc);

# Close the connection.
mysqli_close( $dbc ) ;
?>



<h3>Contact me at jonesypeter@hotmail.com if you would like any information on my plans for this website. Please send me as much feedback and suggestions as possible.</h3>
<h4>Last updated on 28 January 2015</h4>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you echo $q and paste it to your question? Same with $_GET["query"]?

Comment: You're mixing `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` functions. That won't work.

Comment: Don't apply multiple layers of escaping. Escape data only for the use you're applying it to. Specifically, remove this `$query = htmlspecialchars($query); `. Apply it when you're outputting data to the browser.

Comment: If you replace '%".$query."%' with a hardcoded value in your LIKE, does the query work?

Answer (score 0):

Using $_GET can be a bit hard sometimes if you have special characters or spaces in the argument.

I see you treated the $_GET['query'] but if you have spaces you can have a different result.

Please, echo the $q and try to run the result in phpMyAdmin or mysql terminal.
If it works and return the data you want, put this on the very top of your code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
```

and report the error.

By the way, there is no error in the mysqli_error()?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for all the feedback and for treating me gently,  I have added the error report which gives:    
Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: Access denied for user 'retroresource.co.uk'@'10.0.1.170' (using password: NO) in /home/sites/retroresource.co.uk/public_html/retroseek.php on line 48

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: A link to the server could not be established in /home/sites/retroresource.co.uk/public_html/retroseek.php on line 48

Comment: Hello, I have echoed the query and it does not seem to contain the parameter:        http://retroresource.co.uk/retroseek.php?query=Dizzy

Comment: Now seems to be working, not sure what I did but please let me know if you want to see the code. Thanks all

Comment: Let me see.
It will give you an error: 
$query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);
because you're using mysqli, not mysql, like Jay Blanchard said. 
You need to change it to mysqli.

Looks like you made it. It's working now? Good. :)
See ya!

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI, personally, I find this easier to read:

```
"
SELECT g.fgname
     , g.fgprorg
     , g.fgprbud
     , g.fgratng
     , g.fgprdsk
     , t.fttname
     , r.fryymm
     , r.frpage
     , r.frissue
     , m.fmname
     , frefcde.ffname
  FROM fgames g
  JOIN ftypes t
    ON t.fttype = g.fgtype
  JOIN frefs r
    ON r.frlink2 = g.fglink 
  JOIN fmagzne m
    ON m.fmmag = r.frmag 
  JOIN frefcde
    ON frefcde.ffentry = r.frentry 
 WHERE g.fgname LIKE '$query';
";
```